# how can I get current logged in username in Azure SQL database that allows only AD authentication?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I want to define a default constraint on a table which shows that a specific user performed the DML operations on a table.

I define columns as below:

CreatedByUser varchar(50) default system_user

While running the query from the SSMS with my own Id - it gives me correct result i.e. my email ID

When I run the DML operations on the same table through ADF with linked service supporting MSI - I don't get name of the principal ( Data Factory name) - rather I get something like below:

[image]

Can someone please help here?

Comment: Do any of these return values you need? select system_user, SUSER_NAME(), SUSER_SNAME(), user

Answer (score 0):

I created a table with below columns

```
Create table MyTable (Id int, Name varchar(100),CreatedByUser varchar(50) default system_user )
```

I inserted some data into MyTabel through Azure SQL query panel and created stored procedure to run insert values into  MyTable as below:

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE InsertData
@ID INT,
@Name VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
SET  NOCOUNT  ON;
DECLARE @CurrentUser VARCHAR(50);
SELECT @CurrentUser =  SUSER_SNAME();
INSERT  INTO MyTable (ID, Name, CreatedByUser)
VALUES (@ID, @Name, @CurrentUser);
END
```

I created ADF user and assigned roles to the user using below code:

```
create  user [<adfName>] from  external  provider
alter  role db_owner add  member [<adfName>]
```

I created linked service for Azure SQL database through MSI authentication.

[image]

I executed stored procedure with Id, Name parameters executed the pipeline.

[image]

when select data from MyTable with `select  *  from [dbo].[MyTable]`,  I got below output.

[image]

I add new column to the table bu using
`alter  table [dbo].[MyTable] add c_user varchar(50)` and updated below stored procedure as below

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE InsertData
    @ID INT,
    @Name VARCHAR(50),
   @c_user VARCHAR(50)
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET  NOCOUNT  ON;
    DECLARE @CurrentUser VARCHAR(50);
    SELECT @CurrentUser =  SUSER_SNAME();
    INSERT  INTO MyTable (ID, Name, CreatedByUser)
    VALUES (@ID, @Name, @CurrentUser,@c_user);
    END
```

I added dynamic content as `@pipeline().DataFactory` in c_user parameter in stored procedure parameters and executed it.

[image]

I select the data from MyTable with `select  *  from [dbo].[MyTable]` I got my ADF name in 'c_user' column.

[image]